# Set value retrieved from database as string to rating bar in android

Tags: android, database, string, ratingbar

I need to set value retrieved from mysql database (as string) as rating value. I have successfully retrieved the database value to a string . But I don't know how to set this value to rating bar. (for example, if database value that I retrieve in the string is 3, then the rating bar's first 3 stars should indicate that with color change), Please help me with a good support.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RatingBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html) allows you to set the number of displayed stars via its API. Something like below would show you three stars:

```
String yourString = "3"; // TODO read from DB
float rating = Float.parseFloat(yourString);
ratingBar.setRating(rating);
```

Comment: Can you give me an answer for this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31830330/hot-to-reduce-the-space-around-rating-bar-in-android

Answer (score 0):

String yourStringValueFromDatabase = "2"; // you need to read it from sqlite

float ratingBarObq= Float.parseFloat(yourStringValueFromDatabase );

ratingBarObq.setRating(ratingValue); 
//Sets the rating(the number of stars filled).

int numratingStars = Integer.parseInt(somedbvalue);
ratingBarObq.setNumStars(numratingStars);//Sets the number of stars to show.