# How to reduce the space around rating bar in android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, ratingbar

I have included a rating bar in android, and now I need to place a text view to immediate right if the rating bar. But I failed to do the same since, there is a lot of unwanted space (rectangular blue box) around the rating bar, which prevents me from placing the textview to its immediate right side.

Is there any way to reduce this space around the rating bar , so that both the textview and the rating bar comes in same line and textview is placed next to the rating bar without a gap?

Here is my xml code for it.

```
<RatingBar
     android:id="@+id/overall"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
     android:numStars="5"
     android:rating="0.0"
     android:scaleX="0.4"
     android:scaleY="0.4"
     android:stepSize="0.01" />
```

Comment: My text view to be displayed immediate next to rating bar::    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/overallrateid"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:text="overall" />

Answer (score 1):

You can use android default styles, Like:

```
style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.RatingBar.Small"
```

in you xml layout. I am using above and have no space around it.
You can check variants [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use different suggestion but i was unsuccessful with the Android Rating bar removal of extra padding. All i did downloaded ic icons from https://material.io/icons/ and use star and star bordered icon and programmed them with switch cases.

Answer (score 0):

While using the base style for the `RatingBar`, set the `minHeight` to `0dp`. The base `minHeight` in the style itself was preventing the view from scaling down. Setting it to 0 should work as you expect a normal view (we set ours to `wrap_content`).

---

Tried to use the base (`@android:style/Widget.RatingBar`) and small (`@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.RatingBar.Small` and `@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.RatingBar.Small`) but both fixed/limited the size of the the RatingBar regardless of what icon is used. Looking at their codes, it was no surprise.

```
    <style name="Widget.RatingBar">
        <item name="indeterminateOnly">false</item>
        <item name="progressDrawable">@drawable/ratingbar_full</item>
        <item name="indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/ratingbar_full</item>
        <item name="minHeight">57dip</item>
        <item name="maxHeight">57dip</item>
        <item name="thumb">@null</item>
        <item name="mirrorForRtl">true</item>
    </style>
```

```
    <style name="Widget.Material.RatingBar.Small" parent="Widget.RatingBar.Small">
        <item name="progressDrawable">@drawable/ratingbar_small_material</item>
        <item name="indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/ratingbar_small_material</item>
        <item name="minHeight">16dp</item>
        <item name="maxHeight">16dp</item>
    </style>
```

```
    <style name="Widget.Holo.Light.RatingBar.Small" parent="Widget.RatingBar.Small">
        <item name="progressDrawable">@drawable/ratingbar_small_holo_light</item>
        <item name="indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/ratingbar_small_holo_light</item>
        <item name="minHeight">16dip</item>
        <item name="maxHeight">16dip</item>
    </style>
```

Setting the `scale`s didn't work right either.